# How to filter out shortcut from translations

Tags: c++, qt

In QT I have an item named `tr("&Output")` (where the & indicates a short-cut).

Now I want to use the same text without the shortcut - i.e. just "Output" translated to what-ever language, and I could not find this in the documentation.

Added: The reason for doing this is to tell the user to select a menu entry in this case "Output". So if the translation gets out of sync we might have a menu entry "Ausgabe" and telling the user to press "Ausgang", which isn't good. It could be that there is a completely different way of resolving this.

Obviously I can do `tr("Output")` - but that creates the need for additional translation, and the risk that they are inconsistent.

I can also do `tr("&Output").replace("&", "")` - but it seems like a hack. (And would need additional code to handle actual "&" in the text.)

I assume Qt has some internal mechanism for this, but is there a standardized way of accessing it?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a mechanism in Qt for your problem - just make two translations. I like your sample as it shows the weakness of this system in general. "Output" could be meant in the sense of "Printed output" as well as in the sense of "Output Port". In German, the former would be translated as "Ausgabe" the latter as "Ausgang". Hence, I use extra keys for localized texts to catch such cases (and live with the fact that some texts are duplicated and must be translated twice).

Comment: I like your sample as English and German have strong historical relations - not quite easy to find such simple and expressive (counter) examples... :-)

Comment: @Scheff you are right about that being an important consideration as well, but not relevant in this case. The second text is a reference to the first - not merely the same text; but the same thing.

Comment: Yet another idea: If there is such mechanism (what I don't believe) you should find it in other Qt applications e.g. the tools which are shipped with Qt (Qt Creator, etc.) for which there should be localizations available.

Comment: What I would do in this particular case is to make the text `"&" + tr("Output")`, e.g. `button->setText("&" + tr("Output"));`.

Comment: @scopchanov That doesn't work if "&" is in a different position in the translation, which is not unusual.

Comment: @HansOlsson, `button->setText(tr("Output").insert(n, "&"));`

Comment: @scopchanov This may fail if the translation needs a different character (at a different position) as shortcut. Hence, I hardly see any alternative except to provide a translation with `&` (and to remove `&` from the result for the cases where it is needed without).

Comment: @Scheff, I agree with you 100%. Exactly this shows why `"Output"` and `"&Output"` are not the same thing and why they need to be translated differently.

Comment: It seems that handling used internally by QT to filter out this (so that you see "Output") is not exposed, but is internal to qt_format_text when the option Qt::TextHideMnemonic is set.

Comment: Interesting, but I think that the strings with and without shortcut are used in different contexts and therefore should be different translations that could be translated differently if needed.